# React content change based on selected menu with caching

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have this code.

```js
class Component {
  
  state = {
    selectedView: 'foo',
  }
  
  onMenuClicked(event, menuItem) {
    switch(menuItem) {
      case 'foo':
        this.setState({ selectedView: 'foo'})
        break;
      case 'bar':
        this.setState({ selectedView: 'bar'})
        break;
    }
  }
  
  renderBar() {
    return <Bar />    
  }

  renderFoo() {
    return <Foo />  
  }
  
  renderContent() {
    switch(this.state.selectedView) {
      case 'foo':
        return this.renderFoo();
      case 'bar':
        return this.renderBar();
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Menu onMenuSelected((e, menuItem) => this.onMenuClicked(e, menyItem)) /> // items foo and bar
        {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This works fine. However, since foo and bar component are very heavy and the chances of user toggling between these components are high, I would like to have this kind of flow,

- On page load, render foo
- If bar is clicked for the first time, render bar
- For all subsequent menu changes, just hide/show the foo/bar components (based on menu clicked) and don't reload them on every menu change.

I need to adapt my code (the cleanest way possible) to have such behavior. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to use `display: none` on your elements and keeping track of which elements have already been displayed. This way react will always keep the rendered component in the DOM and only update the `display` value.

```
class Component {

  state = {
    selectedView: 'foo',
    foo: true // to indicate that foo has been rendered
  }

  onMenuClicked(event, menuItem) {
    switch(menuItem) {
      case 'foo':
        this.setState({ selectedView: 'foo', foo: true})
        break;
      case 'bar':
        this.setState({ selectedView: 'bar', bar: true})
        break;
    }
  }

  renderBar() {
    const selected = this.state.selectedView === 'bar';

    if (!this.state.bar) {
        return <div/> // don't render bar at all
    }
    return <div style={{display: selected ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
        <Bar />
    </div>
  }

  renderFoo() {
    const selected = this.state.selectedView === 'foo';

    if (!this.state.foo) {
        return <div/> // don't render foo at all
    }
    return <div style={{display: selected ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
        <Foo/>
    </div>
  }

  renderContent() {
    return <div>
        {this.renderFoo()}
        {this.renderBar()}
    <div/>
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Menu onMenuSelected((e, menuItem) => this.onMenuClicked(e, menyItem)) /> // items foo and bar
        {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```